# Lean 4 Invalid Field Notation

Tags: proof, lean

Minimum not-working example:

```
#check Or.intro_left
```

gives

```
error: invalid field notation, type is not of the form (C ...) where C is a constant
  Or
has type
  Prop → Prop → Prop
```

on my machine.

Some experimentation seems to show that the error occurs whenever accessing elements (not sure if that's the correct term) using `.`.

Answer (score 1):

`#check Or.inl` works. I think it's just because there's no declaration called `Or.intro_left` in Lean4.

Comment: Thanks, that's working for me! Just wondering if there's also a lean4 equivalent of Or.elim?

Comment: There's `Or.elim` in mathlib4. Other than that theres just `Or.casesOn`, but the elaborator might have trouble inferring the motive for that.`Or.casesOn` is more complicated than it needs to be for most things.